# NSTableView bindings and tableViewSelectionDidChange

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, cocoa-bindings

I have an NSTableView setup with bindings and I've setup the delegate+dataSource to File's Owner. The table view's elements are not triggering delegate methods. If I click outside the elements, i.e the table view background - `selectionShouldChangeInTableView` is called.

I cannot understand why `tableViewSelectionDidChange` is not called. Seriously why is it so difficult to debug this?

```
-(void)tableViewSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    NSTableView *tableView = [notification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:TABLE_SELECTION object:tableView];

}

- (BOOL)selectionShouldChangeInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView {
    NSLog(@"Hello there");
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Show your implementation of the method or, at least, the method header.

Comment: updated the question.

Comment: Does `selectionShouldChangeInTableView` always return YES?

Comment: @Willeke yes it does. This is exactly my point, isn't there any trace of the responder chain or the events one could follow? I bet this would not be the last time having to debug this

Comment: Did you specifically connect the NSTableView's `delegate` connection to your controller that has the delegate methods?

Comment: Do you remove the delegate as an observer of notifications from the tableview?

Comment: I was adding only one cell, but when I added more cells/rows I could notice the selection and the delegate method being triggered. This was difficult to troubleshoot since I had disabled the cell highlighting in the first place! Not sure if I should close this question or post an answer. Moderators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested in the selected row, you may use the delegate method

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView shouldSelectRow:(NSInteger)rowIndex
```

**BUT** a better approach is to add an observer on selection of the array controller itself, the array controller your table is bound to

```
[myArrayController addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"selection" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];
```

and listen on changes using:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary<NSString *,
                                        id> *)change
                       context:(void *)context
```

and don't forget to remove the observer at the destructor method

```
-(void)dealloc 
{
    [super dealloc];
    [myArrayController removeObserver:self];
}
```